# facebook-appId of the iphone-facebook-app

Tags: iphone, facebook

How do I find out the facebook-appId of the facebookapp for the iphone?
For normal apps, I would simply look at the URL of the facebook-app-"page", but for the Iphone-App, I couldn't find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you are looking for this information, but the id appears to be 6628568379.  See http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=6628568379.

In most cases, you can see the id by looking at the URLs of the images on the application's Facebook page: http://www.facebook.com/iphone

Comment: I wonder, how do you get that info? Is there an API for that?

Comment: Never mind, I got it, the report app link contain the ID too.